# how to portably get the buffer size of a file stream?

Tags: c, stdio

Is there a portable way to retrieve the buffer size used by a stream?

Searching posts online, I've found that `glibc` has a method:

```
size_t __fbufsize (FILE *stream)
```

However, this will only work if I'm using glibc.

It seems that another option is to use the macro `BUFSIZ` and the flags `_IONBF` and `_IOLBF`:

```
void print_buffering(FILE * fp)
{
    if (fp->_flags & _IONBF)
    {
        printf("No buffering\n");
    }
    else if (fp->_flags & _IOLBF)
    {
        printf("Line buffering - buffer size: %d\n", BUFSIZ);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Full buffering - buffer size: %d\n", BUFSIZ);
    }
}
```

Relying on `BUFSIZ` suggests that the buffer size will always be a constant.  Is this always the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Relying on `BUFSIZ` suggests that the buffer size will always be a constant. Is this always the case?

No, it's not.

In the call to `setvbuf`

```
int setvbuf(FILE * restrict stream, char * restrict buf, int mode, size_t size);
```

You can choose the value for `size` yourself. (Although you may choose to use `BUFSIZE`) The macro `BUFSIZE` only works when you call `setbuf`

```
void setbuf(FILE * restrict stream, char * restrict buf);
```

It is equivalent to the `setvbuf` function invoked with the values `_IOFBF` for mode and `BUFSIZ` for size, or (if `buf` is a null pointer), with the value `_IONBF` for mode.

Comment: So is the answer "No, there's no portable way"?

Comment: @Yu Hao - so do I need to exercise some care if I make a call to `setvbuf` in my module, because anyone using my module who later reads `BUFSIZ` in their code will now have a false value?

Comment: @Chris I think so, especially when you use self-appointed buffer when calling `sevbuf`. Maybe there is another way to get the buffer size, just I didn't find out yet.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at fbufmode() from gnulib which attempts to do this portably